# Making a spinning spiral

Tags: javascript, animation, rotation, spiral

I have found a code to draw spiral and I need to make it spin 360 degrees (something like hypnotizing effect). I tried to animate it, but I don't know how to implement it properly. I am running out of time. It would be great if that code would be as simple as possible.

Here's the spiral code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var cxt=c.getContext("2d");
    var centerX = 150;
    var centerY = 150;
    cxt.moveTo(centerX, centerY);

    var STEPS_PER_ROTATION = 60;
    var increment = 2*Math.PI/STEPS_PER_ROTATION;       
    var theta = increment;

    while( theta < 40*Math.PI) {
      var newX = centerX + theta * Math.cos(theta); 
      var newY = centerY + theta * Math.sin(theta); 
      cxt.lineTo(newX, newY);
      theta = theta + increment;
    }
    cxt.stroke();
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps this page will help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Transformations

Answer (score 2):

While [Xotic750's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16287373/238722) is much better because there's no mathematical recalculation constantly happening, [here's the jsFiddle of a JavaScript-only alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/X2gp3/1/). The advantage this version provides is for backwards compatibility on browsers with no [CSS3 animation support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation).

CSS3 animation support has only come recently to Firefox, Safari, Internet Explorer, and Opera (Desktop, Mobile, and Mini). Chrome (Desktop and Mobile), and BlackBerry Browser are the only ones shown to have supported animations from a very early stage.

---

Explanation:

```
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    DrawSpiral(counter);
    counter += 0.075;
}, 10);
```

- `counter` is a variable that will keep *count* of the position that the spiral should be at on the next redraw.
- `DrawSpiral` is the function that does the actual job.

There are two factors that will help with changing the speed of the spin; the change in `counter` (`+= 0.075`) and the `setInterval` delay (`50`).

The two factors should be inversely proportional. In other words, **increasing** the `setInterval` delay should go hand-in-hand with **decreasing** the counter change.

---

Changes from your original:

```
cxt.save();
cxt.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

cxt.beginPath();
```

- Encapsulated your spiral-drawing code into the `DrawSpiral(...)` function.
- `cxt.save()` stores the current transformations.
- `cxt.clearRect(...)` clears the canvas (so as to not draw on top of the previous drawing).
- `cxt.beginPath()` starts a new line path (essentially *cutting* off from the last one).

Next set of changes:

```
var newX = centerX + theta * Math.cos(theta - mod);
var newY = centerY + theta * Math.sin(theta - mod);
```

- `... Math.cos(theta - mod)` changes the `newX` value to the next "*spot*".
- `... Math.sin(theta - mod)` changes the `newY` value to the next "*spot*".

---

Do keep in mind that this method *may* be a little bit slower depending on the browser, CPU, graphics card, etc.

Comment: +1 Nice job! Are there any browsers that support HTML5 canvas but not CSS3? Just wondering ...

Comment: @Xotic750 The differences I found were on older versions of Firefox, Safari, IE, and Opera (desktop, mini, mobile). All of them have [supported canvas](http://caniuse.com/canvas) for quite a few versions, however, CSS3's [animation](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) has come only recently to some. Chrome (desktop and mobile) and BlackBerry Browser are the only ones that seem to have support for both from a very early stage.

Answer (score 1):

ok, here is one solution using CSS animation rather than mathematical calculation.

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes myCanvas {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes myCanvas {
    0% { -moz-transform: rotateZ(360deg); }
    100% { moz-transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
}
@keyframes myCanvas {
    0% { transform: rotateZ(360deg); }
    100% { transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
}

#myCanvas {
    -webkit-animation: myCanvas 2s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: myCanvas 2s infinite linear;
    animation: myCanvas 2s infinite linear;
}
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var cxt = c.getContext("2d");
var centerX = 150;
var centerY = 150;
cxt.moveTo(centerX, centerY);

var STEPS_PER_ROTATION = 60;
var increment = 2 * Math.PI / STEPS_PER_ROTATION;
var theta = increment;

while (theta < 40 * Math.PI) {
    var newX = centerX + theta * Math.cos(theta);
    var newY = centerY + theta * Math.sin(theta);
    cxt.lineTo(newX, newY);
    theta = theta + increment;
}

cxt.stroke();
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/fpM33/)

Comment: Thank you for your response!

I tried to put in in Dreamweaver but it doesn't work. 
Any suggestions where i may be wrong?

Comment: Not the foggiest, I don' use Dreamweaver- Can't say that an editor will behave like a browser.

Comment: So could you kindly please look at this and give any tips?
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/29/codeqf.jpg/

Comment: I don't see any of the #myCanvas css commands as given merged into your work.

Comment: If I understood right you were talking about this. It doesn't change anything. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/521/code2.jpg/?sa=0

I need this so much to be working.

Comment: And now what if you serve that page to a browser (which you tested the solution on my jsfiddle with) rather than Dreamweaver?. You can just open the file locally with you browser.

Comment: That's the thing. It doesn't work either on Dreamweaver or opening locally with a browser. I tried Mozilla and Chrome. I still cannot realize how it works on jsFiddle.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "doesn't work" but try putting your javascript within an onload event.